# Get the value of SEWorkflowStates in the SEActions for the corresponding property that matches the string value

Tags: c#

```
 public class SEWorkflow
{
  public SEActions SEAction { get; set; }
  public string nextuser { get; set; }
}

 public class SEActions
    {
        public SEWorkflowStates OnApprove { get; set; }
        public SEWorkflowStates OnReject { get; set; }
        public SEWorkflowStates OnSubmit { get; set; }
    }
 public enum SEWorkflowStates
    {
        Nothing,
        DonotDisturb,

    }
```

Now I have the workflow instance and a variable in the form of string called OnApprove/OnReject/OnSubmit

```
public SEWorkflowStates mapper(SEWorkflow workflow, string action)
{
  // action = OnApprove or OnReject or OnSubmit 
if(action == "OnApprove")
{
  return workflow.SEActions.OnApprove 
}
if(action == "OnReject ")
{
  return workflow.SEActions.OnReject 
}
if(action == "OnSubmit")
{
  return workflow.SEActions.OnSubmit
}
}
```

With this I have to get the value of SEWorkflowStates in the SEActions for the corresponding property that matches the string value. I used If statement but is clumsy. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: use [switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements#the-switch-statement)  ?

Answer (score 2):

There are several options, including switch expressions or using reflection to find the property by its name. But usually when I see a pattern like this, it indicates that a POCO class might be the wrong data structure. Consider using a `Dictionary<string, SEWorkflowStates>` in place of the `SEActions` class.

```
public class SEWorkflow
{
  public Dictionary<string, SEWorkflowStates> SEActions { get; set; }
}
```

```
SEWorkflowStates states = workflow.SEActions[action];
```

Comment: will this work. can you show me a running code. I tried and I failed

Comment: Looks like a better design, thanks